# Best way to remove ordered sequential duplicates in a comma separated list with postgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a column with data that looks like this in a single field:

"a,a,b,b,c,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,c,a,a,b"

Using some sort of regex or SQL function I would like to make it look like this:

"a,b,c,a,b,a,c,a,b"

Essentially I am trying to get rid of repeated values that appear in order but keep the unique changes from one value to another.

My knowledge of reg-expressions pretty much ends at removing duplicates. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use regexp:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('a,a,b,b,c,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,c,a,a,b', '(\w)(,\1)+', '\1', 'g')
```

`(\w)(,\1)+` mutches: (any word char) and following (`,` and this same word char) more than one time...

[Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/59aac/1)
[RegExr example](https://regexr.com/4q1sg)

Comment: I used this answer changing this piece '(\w)(,\1)+' to '(\w+)(,\1)+' in order to catch a couple longer strings. 

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the elements into rows, check if the previous row is different to the current and then keep only those where something changed. This can then be aggregated back into a comma separated list:

```
select string_agg(ch, ',' order by idx)
from (
 select u.ch, u.idx, 
        coalesce(u.ch <> lag(u.ch) over (order by u.idx), true) as is_change
 from unnest(string_to_array('a,a,b,b,c,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,c,a,a,b', ',')) with ordinality as u(ch, idx)
) t
where is_change
```

The `with ordinality` returns the original array index, so that we can sort the elements correctly when aggregating them.

This can also be put into a function:

```
create or replace function cleanup(p_input text)
  returns text
as
$$
  select string_agg(ch, ',' order by idx)
  from (
   select u.ch, u.idx, 
          coalesce(u.ch <> lag(u.ch) over (order by u.idx), true) as is_change
   from unnest(string_to_array(p_input, ',')) with ordinality as u(ch, idx)
  ) t
  where is_change;
$$
language sql;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5b002ef6587f1d6518ebf649b951c266)

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is:

If the character is the same as previous character, you want to remove it from the string.

So I will use while loop and if statement in this case:

```
--CREATE TABLE TEST (ID VARCHAR(100));
--INSERT INTO TEST VALUES ('a,a,b,b,c,a,b,b,b,a,a,a,a,a,a,c,a,a,b');

DO $$
DECLARE  
   V_NEWSTRING VARCHAR(100) := '';  
   V_I INTEGER := 1;
   V_LENGTH INTEGER := 0;
   V_CURRENT VARCHAR(10) := '';
   V_LAST VARCHAR(10) := '';
BEGIN  
   SELECT LENGTH(ID) FROM TEST INTO V_LENGTH;
   WHILE V_I <= V_LENGTH LOOP
     SELECT SUBSTRING(ID,V_I,1) from TEST INTO V_CURRENT;
     IF V_CURRENT <> V_LAST THEN
       V_NEWSTRING = V_NEWSTRING || V_CURRENT || ',';
     END IF;
     V_LAST = V_CURRENT;
     V_I = V_I + 2;
   END LOOP;
   raise notice 'Value: %', V_NEWSTRING;
END $$;
```

---

Test Result (PostgreSQL-9.4):

[image]